# Kitty terminal automatically deselects text?

Tags: clipboard, kitty

Every time I highlight text to copy from the Kitty terminal, it automatically deselects it. This is creating a situation where I cannot copy from the terminal.

What might be causing this behaviour?

Comment: This certainly isn't normal kitty behavior. Anything relevant in your kitty.conf?